# Node.js: setInterval function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, setinterval

I'm emulating data using the Mockaroo API. Then I want to post them every second in my database. So when I test the post method using Postman it works well, but when I try to use `setInterval()` it doesn't work and it doesn't show any error. I figured out that my database is empty, so it doesn't post the data.
Here's my code :

```
function Post (){ 
/*router.post('/tu',*/
function P(req, res, next) {
    var result;
var inde=["Ariana","Beja"];
    for (var o=0; o<inde.length; o++) {

    client.generate({
    count: 2,
    schema: inde[o]+' indexes'
}).then(function(records) {
     for (var i=0; i<records.length; i++) {
        var record = records[i];
        var c = new models.pollution(record);
         c.save(function(err, records){
        if(err) res.json({error: err});
        result=records;
        });        
    }
})
}
res.json(result);
console.log("success");
}
};
setInterval(Post,1000);
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: The `Post` function doesn't do anything. It just defines a function `P` and never calls it.

Comment: So how can i make it work ??

Comment: You can make the function P as a IFFY(Immediately-invoked function expression) function

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are not calling the function "P"  that you define inside the "POST" function. You can make the function P as a
IFFY(Immediately-invoked function expression) function.

```
function Post (){ 
    /*router.post('/tu',*/
    (function P(req, res, next){
        var result;
        var inde=["Ariana","Beja"];
        for (var o=0; o<inde.length; o++) {

            client.generate({
                    count: 2,
                    schema: inde[o]+' indexes'
            }).then(function(records) {
                for (var i=0; i<records.length; i++) {
                    var record = records[i];
                    var c = new models.pollution(record);
                    c.save(function(err, records){
                            if(err) res.json({error: err});
                            result=records;
                    });        
                }
            })
        }
        res.json(result);
        console.log("success");
    })(req, res, next);
};
setInterval(Post,1000);
```

Comment: Thank you for responding , but when i did it like you proposed  i got : Cannot read property 'json' of undefined .

Comment: @RaoufHammami   I have updated the answer. check now

Comment: Same issue but this time req is not defined

Comment: setInterval(function() { Post(req, res, next),1000 });

Comment: @danday74  thank you for responding , but i got the same result when i did it : req is not defined

Comment: ok so given my code above you are passing req to your Post function, which is passing req to your P function - however req is never set so you are just passing undefined everytime, you need to see why it is undefined - i expect if you console.log(req) just before you call setInterval it will be undefined - please investigate why as that is your issue - also, your function P does not need a name - leave it as an anonymous function

Comment: @danday74 i did like you said and it worked like a charm , also i removed the three parameters req,res,next because i figure that they are useless since i don't use any route and i declared only one function. Thank you so much

Comment: no problem glad to hear you have it fixed ... also ... i said "given my code above" .... apologies it was not my code lol ... God bless you